# TCP/IP Sequence Prediction Blind Reset Spoofing DoS

Tags: security, networking, google-cloud-platform, tcp, spoofing

After a security scan the team returned this risk on our product, which is deployed on GCP as App Engine and is basically the frontend of our product.

**Name**:- TCP/IP Sequence Prediction Blind Reset Spoofing DoS.

**Synopsis**:- It was possible to send spoofed RST packets to the remote system.

**Description**:- The remote host is affected by a sequence number approximation vulnerability that allows an attacker to send spoofed RST packets to the remote host and close established connections. This may cause problems for some dedicated services (BGP, a VPN over TCP, etc).

How can we solve this and remove this risk from our product?

Answer (score 0):

You didn’t share what type of tool is used to made this security scan but based on your comments I assume that is regarding the vulnerability [CVE-2004-0230](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2004-0230) that is considered as a false positive as well as GCP passed some of the [compliance things](https://cloud.google.com/security/compliance/), as a plus Google Cloud is NIST [800-171](https://cloud.google.com/security/compliance/nist800-171/) and [800-53](https://cloud.google.com/security/compliance/nist800-53/) compliant

This is fixed now in recent kernels. The [kernel fix](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/?id=282f23c6ee343126156dd41218b22ece96d747e3) references [RFC 5961 section 3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5961#section-3) which deals with the same issue.